# Looping through database table data and displaying it in a proper format

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in the database.

**TABLE ROOM** has the following columns and data

```
id(int)    room_type(varchar)      price(int)
 1           single room              25000
 2           double room              50000
```

And **TABLE ROOM_IMAGE** has the following columns and data

```
id(int)     image(varchar)         room_id(int)
 1            single.jpg                 1
 2            single1.jpg                1
 3            double.jpg                 2
```

When i use the following PHP code:

```
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT a.room_type, s.image FROM room as a 
            JOIN room_image as s
            ON a.id = s.room_id ";
?>
<?php if ($rooms = $mysqli->query($query)) { ?>

  <?php while ($room = $rooms->fetch_object()) { ?>

    <h4><?php echo $room->type; ?></h4>
    <p><?php echo $room->image; ?></p>

  <?php } ?>

<?php } ?>
```

I get the following results:

```
        single room
       single.jpg
    single room
           single1.jpg
    double room
           double.jpg
```

Yet i want my results to display as follows

```
        single room
           single.jpg
           single1.jpg
        double room
           double.jpg
```

So could somebody help me on write the proper php syntax to produce the desired result (preferably using a join sql statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add an `ORDER BY` clause to your query, based on room type. This will line up all the rooms of each type together

```
$query = "SELECT a.room_type, s.image FROM room as a 
        JOIN room_image as s
        ON a.id = s.room_id  ORDER BY a.room_type";
```

Then, display a type only if it was not displayed before. Use an extra variable to keep track of it.

```
 <?php 
  $lastType="";
  while ($room = $rooms->fetch_object())
    { 
      if($lastType!=$room->type) 
      {
       echo "<h4>",$room->type,"</h4>";
      }
      echo "<p>",$room->image,"</p>";
      $lastType=$room-type;          // This variable keeps track of room type display
    } 
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Hanky 웃 Panky. Makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a join query. Just add the images to a field under the room table and query just one table.

**Database:**

```
id(int)    room_type(varchar)      price(int)    images(varchar)
 1           single room              25000         ["single.jpg","single1.jpg"]
 2           double room              50000         ["double.jpg"]
```

**PHP:**

```
$images = json_decode($room->image);
foreach($images as $image){
  echo $image;
}
```

Comment: That would be a terrible database design

Comment: That would violate database design rules of Fisrt normal form of no repeating groups and each cell in a table should contain one value.

Comment: I have seen databases use JSON arrays do to the fact that storing individual values into there own table and record would be absurd and degrade performance when queried for all the values. By the way, rules are meant to be broken.

Comment: Thanks for the great idea anyway @user2067005, would probably use it some other time but not right now. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem. In all honestly, it's best to do it the way you are. Easier to manage the pictures.